# Error while running Spring-boot: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot

I'm quite new to spring boot application. I have created that code and it was running in other machine but when I took it in my machine it's producing the error.

Code is also available in GIT :
https://github.com/pramendra0510/Spring-Boot-MVC-Rest-Sample-Project

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-31 10:27:48.873 ERROR 3773 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at my.spring.Application.main(Application.java:9) [classes/:na]`

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:64) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.createJpaVendorAdapter(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d472599.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$3(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d472599$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f1e82152.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d472599.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myproject
spring.datasource.username:root
spring.datasource.password:12345
spring.datasource.driver-class-name:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql:true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
logging.level.org.org.hibernate.SQL:debug
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.0.0.M1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.6</version> -->
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>Spring</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: At your machine the `hibernate-core.jar` seems missing. Try building your project again with maven goals `clean install`. If that doesn't resolve include the following dependency `<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>` and rebuild.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond I have tried with also but still the same error is coming.

Comment: Check in local repository if the particular jar is available or not. Moreover check the maven settings if any proxy is preventing the download

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond yeah I have, hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then `mvn clean verify` to force a renownload of the jars. Might be that you have an empty/corrupted jar in your repository.

Comment: Code in the Git link is working fine without any errors

Comment: Thank you all for your support, the problem has been resolved. I just remove all the jars and build again, now it's working fine.